# Python replace 3 random characters in a string with no duplicates

Tags: python, algorithm

I need change 3 random characters in a string using Python, example string:

```
Adriano Celentano 
Luca Valentina
```

I need to replace 3 characters, not replacing with the same character or number, not replacing space. How can I do this using Python ?

Need output like this :

```
adraano cettntano
lacr vilenntina
```

I don't know from where i can start to make this.

My code so far:

```
for i in xrange(4):
    for n in nume :
        print n.replace('$', random.choice(string.letters)).replace('#', random.choice(string.letters))
```

Comment: why are you looping 4 times and how do  `'$'` and `'#'` fit into it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to change chars that are not  whitespace and not the same char in regards to index, you can first pull the indexes where the  non-whitespace chars are:

```
import random
inds = [i for i,_ in enumerate(s) if not s.isspace()]

print(random.sample(inds,3))
```

Then use those indexes to replace.

```
s = "Adriano Celentano"
import random
inds = [i for i,_ in enumerate(s) if not s.isspace()]
sam = random.sample(inds, 3)
from string import ascii_letters

lst = list(s)
for ind in sam:
    lst[ind] = random.choice(ascii_letters)

print("".join(lst))
```

If you want a unique char each time to replace with also:

```
s = "Adriano Celentano"
import random
from string import ascii_letters
inds = [i for i,_ in enumerate(s) if not s.isspace()]

sam = random.sample(inds, 3)

letts =  iter(random.sample(ascii_letters, 3))
lst = list(s)
for ind in sam:
    lst[ind] = next(letts)

print("".join(lst))
```

output:

```
Adoiano lelenhano
```

Comment: Instead of excluding numbers and spaces, I think it's safer to include only letters via `set('your string...') & set('abcdef...')`

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini,  it depends on what the OP wants to replace, there is some ambiguity in the question in regard to what they actually want to replace

Comment: `set('your string') & set(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase)` even

Comment: in case the string contains space and punctuation, how about "inds = [i for i,_ in enumerate(s) if _.isalpha()]"?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two stages. In the first stage you pick 3 random positions in your string that meet your search criteria (`isalnum`):

```
import random
import string
replacement_chars='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'
# replacement_chars = string.letters + string.digits
input = 'Adriano Celentano'
input_list = list(input) 
input_dic = dict(enumerate(input_list))
valid_positions=[key for key in input_dic if input_dic[key].isalnum()]
random_positions=random.sample(valid_positions,3)
```

In the second part you generate 3 random characters and replace the characters in the previously selected positions. I have added a while loop to generate a new random character if it matches the existing value

```
random_chars = random.sample(replacement_chars,len(random_positions)) 
char_counter = 0
for position in random_positions:   
    #check if the replacement character matches the existing one
    #and generate another one if needed
    while input_list[position]==random_chars[char_counter]:
        random_chars[char_counter] = random.choice(replacement_chars)    
    input_list[position]=random_chars[char_counter]    
    char_counter = char_counter + 1
print "".join(input_list).lower()
```

Comment: Why use `random.sample` when you want a single element?